# Replacing custom events in GTK4

Tags: c++, gtk

In one of my projects in GTK3, I am using custom events for communication between threads. One thread is the main OS thread on which the event loop is running. The other one is a non main thread that is doing some internal application specific initialization. The condition is that the first GTK window shall be created, only after the application is initialized. However, I don’t want to delay the main thread entering the event loop for some design related reasons.

Therefore, the main thread enters the event loop as soon as GTK is initialized and the non main thread needs to intimate the main thread when first window can be created. For this intimations I am using custom events in GTK3 (it can be created although I am not sure it is recommended or not).

The code snippet for the non main thread creating custom event is as below -

```
GdkEvent *  createwinevent;

// Create and post custom event to start GTK Window creation

createwinevent = gdk_event_new ((GdkEventType) CREATE_WINDOW);               

// CREATE_WINDOW is an enum defined by the application

gdk_event_put (createwinevent);
```

In the main thread, I am using `g_idle_timeout` to check the event queue intermittently and handle the custom events.

In GTK4 however, GdkEvents have been made read-only. Can custom events still be created in GTK4 somehow? If not, is there any other mechanism I can use in GTK4 to pass message between threads?

Reading through GTK4 materials could not find anything to support custom events.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from the [Migrating from Gtk 3.x to GTK4](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html) (Section [Adapt to `GdkEvent` API changes](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#adapt-to-gdkevent-api-changes)):

> Direct access to `GdkEvent` structs is no longer possible in GTK 4.
> `GdkEvent` is now a strictly read-only type, and you can no longer
> change any of its fields, **or construct new events**. All event fields
> have accessors that you will have to use.

So it think what you are doing is no longer possible in GTK4.

Comment: That's correct @BobMorane. An elaborate explanation is given in response to exactly this question, by one of the GTK developers, see here: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/replacing-custom-events-in-gtk4/11967